# Can I override a new instance of a class object?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm not sure what it's called but you can override methods easily with:

```
Apple foo = new Apple(){
    public void devour(){
        //Devour apple
    }
};
```

And you can get the Class of an object with getClass.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
Apple a = new Apple();
Class<? extends Apple> B = a.getClass();
Apple c = new B(){
    public void polish(){
        //Polish apple
    }
};
```

Side Note: I'm asking this question because I specifically want to override a single method in the current swing UI class for a component returned by `UIManager.getUI(component).getClass()` in [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10136/implementing-a-jtabbedpane-with-detached-content-pane).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code snippet you are creating an anonymous subclass of `Apple` which overrides the `devour()` method, and then instantiating `foo` as an instance of this anonymous subclass.

In the second example, and in your goal, you cannot change the class/type of an object reference *after that object already exists*.